# Updating kubernetes-dashboard image in a Azure acs-k8s cluster is not getting reflected

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dashboard, acs

Action:

Tried updating the kubernetes-dashboard in k8s hosted in azure acs with image `gcrio.azureedge.net/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64` from version `v1.6.3` to `v1.7.1` (latest).

Problem:

The image version, when edited either with kubectl or UI, is not getting reflected/updated.

Question:

Is there any way to update the image version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be getting updated but then reverted by the k8s addon manager. If you ssh into a master the templates for the addon services live in `etc/kubernetes/addons`.

To upgrade the image you can edit `/etc/kubernetes/addons/kubernetes-dashboard-deployment.yaml` and change `image` inside the *Deployment* spec.

Your change should be picked up in a few seconds.

Comment: **State of ACS as of June 12th, 2018:** ACS deploys a Kubernetes cluster with version 1.7. The latest fully supported version of Kubernetes Dashboard is therefore 1.7.1. See [upstream compatability matrix](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Compatibility-matrix) for more information. Deploying Dashboard version => 1.8.0 will not work properly.